# Issue with Linux multi user creation using bash script

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, scripts, ssh

As per our requirement we provided our devloper group: `devs:r-x to`  `/var/log/httpd directory`.
Now I'm  creating a Linux function  , which take the developer's first name and create a linux user in our development environment

**I have tried this code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

CREATE_USER_NAME="pi"

# Create account
echo "============= now create an account ============="
sudo useradd -s /usr/bin/fish -m $CREATE_USER_NAME
sudo usermod -aG devs $CREATE_USER_NAME
sudo passwd $CREATE_USER_NAME

if getent passwd "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "yes the user exists"
else
    echo "No, the user does not exist"
fi
mkdir -p /home/santosh/.ssh
chmod 0700 /home/santosh/.ssh
touch /home/santosh/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /home/santosh/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/santosh-dev.jove.com/
sudo chown -R santosh /var/www/html/santosh-dev.jove.com/
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/httpd/santosh-dev.jove.com/
sudo chown -R santosh /var/log/httpd/santosh-dev.jove.com/
#
```

**Output I Received:**

```
[santosh@skb Desktop]$ ./user1.sh
============= now create an account =============
[sudo] password for santosh: 
useradd: user 'pi' already exists
Changing password for user pi.
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is a palindrome
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
No, the user does not exist
```

we have a **devs group** in our developer server, and now automate the task and want to create a Linux function for 10 plus developers (user).

what is the best advice here! I'm unable to figure it what is wrong here? can anyone guide me on it!

If you have time, any help at all would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be another continuation of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406084/issue-with-group-function) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405942/group-creation-function-issue) and also [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700868/group-creation-function-issue) - it's still not clear to me whether you are asking about how to implement something, or for help developing your requirements?

Comment: I Want to make a Linux function on our dev server (10.0.10.163) that will create developers (users)? with mentioned requirements.
I have tried this, can you advise or pointed out what is wrong I have done with the function?

Comment: I have tried this :

#!bin/bash
# sudo useradd -g devs username
# sudo usermod -a -G devs exampleusername
# mkdir -m 700 ${HOME}/.ssh
# touch $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
# chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
# cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
# sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html/dev.mysite.com/
# sudo mkdir -p /var/log/dev.mysite.com/
# sudo chmod -R 744 /var/log/dev.mysite.com/
# sudo chown -R username /var/www/html/dev.mysite.com/
# sudo chown ${USER:=$(/usr/bin/id -run)}:$USER /var/www/$dev.mysite.com

Comment: @santoshbaruah Please post your question only *once* on Ask Ubuntu; a very similar question has been seen multiple times on this site, in the last few days.

Comment: yes sure! is there any advise why I'm getting Operation not permitted and Permission denied here ? (I'm the root user here )

Comment: start by actually providing a username?  Those paths as is will NOT work with empty arguments as written.

Comment: can you pl describe a bit ? is usermod -a -G devs sam ? will work here ?

Comment: There's no clear question here. You don't provide complete input, nor complete error messages.

Comment: This is the output I received " chmod: changing permissions of '/home//.ssh': Operation not permitted
touch: cannot touch '/home//.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied"

Comment: Yes, because $1 was not defined. How do you run your scripts? Please read the feedback you get, and answer the questions, don't repost your questions willy-nilly.

Comment: Cloud you pl describe a bit with an example?